# Json to fullcalendar object

Tags: javascript, json, django, xmlhttprequest, fullcalendar

I'm new to using fullcalendar and I cant quite wrap my head around turning the json request to plot on the calendar

My model instead of using title, start, end, and all_day

Is instead using                 name, start_date, completion_date, all_day

as a result the calendar wont render the objects from my model onto the fullcalendar

My views.py is

```
def view_calendar(request):
jobs = Job.objects.all()
return HttpResponse(events_to_json(jobs), content_type='application/json')
```

THIS IS GENERATING A JSON OBJECT SHOWN AS

```
[{"completionDate": "2015-11-06", "startDate": "2015-11-06", "allDay": false, "name": "342345", "id": 7}, {"completionDate": "2017-04-30", "startDate": "2017-02-19", "allDay": false, "name": "Calendars", "id": 9}, 
{"completionDate": "2015-02-28", "startDate": "2015-02-26", "allDay": false, "name": "Lowe's Remodel ", "id": 4}, {"completionDate": "2015-02-04", "startDate": "2015-01-18", "allDay": false, "name": "Lowe's Remodel 2", "id": 1}, 
{"completionDate": "2015-09-13", "startDate": "2015-05-13", "allDay": false, "name": "Lowe's Remodel 3", "id": 5}, {"completionDate": "2017-04-30", "startDate": "2017-04-21", "allDay": false, "name": "WONDER", "id": 10}, 
{"completionDate": "2015-09-03", "startDate": "2015-08-03", "allDay": false, "name": "aaa gfdsgfs dgfgsd daaa gfdsgfs dgfgsd daaa gfdsgfs dgfgsd daaa gfdsgfs dgfgsd d", "id": 6}, 
{"completionDate": "2016-04-22", "startDate": "2015-02-24", "allDay": false, "name": "dgfs3344", "id": 3},
{"completionDate": "2015-02-26", "startDate": "2015-02-01", "allDay": false, "name": "gfdgdfs", "id": 2}, 
{"completionDate": "2015-11-06", "startDate": "2015-11-06", "allDay": false, "name": "ssssgf", "id": 8}]
```

I have no idea how to render this object onto the fullcalendar because it doesn't seem to take these arguments even with this json

I appreciate these answers however I ma not have clarified, I've parsed my  models into fullcalendar format with

```
    `return HttpResponse(events_to_json(jobs).replace('name', 'title').replace("startDate", "start").replace('completionDate', 'end'), content_type='application/json')`
```

In Django this renders a url /output/ which dumps all of these values like 
`[{"end": "2015-11-06", "start": "2015-11-06", "title": "342345"}, {"end": "2015-02-28", "start": "2015-02-26", "title": "Lowe's Remodel "}, {"end": "2015-02-04", "start": "2015-01-18", "title": "Lowe's Remodel 2"}, {"end": "2015-09-13", "start": "2015-05-13", "title": "Lowe's Remodel 3"}, {"end": "2015-09-03", "start": "2015-08-03", "title": "aaa gfdsgfs dgfgsd daaa gfdsgfs dgfgsd daaa gfdsgfs dgfgsd daaa gfdsgfs dgfgsd d"}, {"end": "2016-04-22", "start": "2015-02-24", "title": "dgfs3344"}, {"end": "2015-02-26", "start": "2015-02-01", "title": "gfdgdfs"}, {"end": "2015-11-06", "start": "2015-11-06", "title": "ssssgf"}]`

My question was how do i return this url that contains a ready to use json format into my Fullcalendar Events:?

Answer (score 0):

A fullcalendar event needs at least a **title** and a **start** property. Your django code should return the format fullcalendar expects, so you need to adjust your view to return the correct json. Things you need to adjust:

- name should be title
- startDate should be start
- completionDate should be end

[Here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) you can find all properties of en Event object.

Comment: What @dentemm said - also, if you can just use the URL endpoint you use to generate the JSON as your event source, in the success callback, you can reformat the actual JSON into something that fullcalendar accepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/) Callback. It allows you to take data that may not exactly work with fullcalendar and transform it to where fullcalendar can render it properly.